# Can't assign field values in flow loop to text collection variable?

Tags: visual-workflow, collection, collection-variable

I'm trying to create a flow that loops through a child object of account (child account).

The goal is to loop through various fields for each child account, e.g. platform, assign these values to a collection (text collection variable) and then do some logic on the collection to update the parent account - e.g. loop through all child accounts, get the platform value from each one and store in a collection.  After the loop, get all unique values and assign them to a multi select picklist value on the account.

There are other logic updates I need to make but they are all similar in functionality - e.g. loop through all child accounts, store the status of each in a collection.  After the loop, store the status based on hierarchy (e.g. active is always first, closed is last) and update the account rating.

The fields I'm trying to store values from are different data types, but I don't understand why I can't store them in a text collection. I tried to store directly from the current loop item but it doesn't show me the field I want to store the value from.  Also tried to create a single text variable, store the value in that, and then assign the platform to the collection variable from the single variable but it doesn't give me the single variable as an option either.

How to I achieve this?  Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?  Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I believe you should be able to use the Operator "Add" to add a value to the collection?